# pygamevideo module not able to import

Tags: python

I am fairly new to python and am trying to import the pygamevideo module, but I keep getting an error message that tells me that there is "No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'" I pasted the error below. I am using repl.it.

Thanks for any help I get.

```
pip install pygamevideo

Collecting pygamevideo
  Downloading pygamevideo-1.0.0.tar.gz (2.6 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /opt/virtualenvs/python3/bin/python3 -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-j5bka7jd/pygamevideo_676e088740714a8391a075734662c062/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-j5bka7jd/pygamevideo_676e088740714a8391a075734662c062/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-yoytu39b
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-j5bka7jd/pygamevideo_676e088740714a8391a075734662c062/
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-j5bka7jd/pygamevideo_676e088740714a8391a075734662c062/setup.py", line 28, in <module>
        install_requires=open("requirements.txt", "r").readlines()
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6e/b2/63f63e37b75bb1efb7d51b055366a52fad92b765a08ec89cfd7a2b5bd6f0/pygamevideo-1.0.0.tar.gz#sha256=7e64da54a116f6b68fdfa5d72425c59cb6ba95ab59514f018e8e3bcdef73100f (from https://pypi.org/simple/pygamevideo/) (requires-python:>=3.6). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygamevideo (from versions: 1.0.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pygamevideo
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.dev0; however, version 21.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/opt/virtualenvs/python3/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: pygamevideo needs python >= 3.6. What version of python are yuo using?

Comment: also better to upgrade pip as well ( as it been mentioned in the error message by running : `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip` command.

Comment: even worse I can't find that module on github , there is no documentation either.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like outdated programs. Try upgrading `pip` and then using `pip3` (worked for me), also upgrade python because it just says `python3` but for me, it says `python3.9`. Also, try looking up the module on PyPI. It might help you out.

Comment: I tried that and It didn't work. I am using version 3.8.12.  I am using repl.it, how should I update the version?

Comment: did this issue occur for only this module or does this happen for every module?